# sfEasyGMapPlugin won't show the Google Map

Tags: plugins, symfony1

I've just started to use the sfEasyGMapPlugin, in my Symfony website. So I've followed the samples and created a basic map, to check if it works.

In the action :

```
$this->gMap = new GMap();
$this->gMap->setCenter(50.637551,3.062725);
```

And in the template :

```
<?php use_helper('Javascript','GMap') ?>

<?php include_map($gMap,array('width'=>'700px','height'=>'400px')); ?>

<!-- Javascript included at the bottom of the page -->
<?php include_map_javascript($gMap); ?>
```

I've signed up some api keys for my domains like `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` and defined them in my app.yml.

Now, when I go to the page, the canvas shows up with it's control buttons, but **the map do not shows up** (there is only a grey background).

There is no error, everything seems to be configured fine. I can center the map on a point, like in the action above, but it do nothing.

I've tried to use the html code given by Google with my api keys and it works fine. So I really don't understand.

Am I doing it wrong ?

Regards,
Timothée Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got  my answer...

You must define the center AND the zoom level with :

```
$this->gMap->setCenter(latitude, longitude);
$this->gMap->setZoom(level);
```

After that, the map shows up normally.

Hope it helps...